# How can I create a dictionary filled with output from processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to create a dictionary which is filled with data returned from processes each themselves running a function which expects multiple arguments.

```
#list_of_values is a list of integer values, value1 und value2 are strings
def example(list_of_values, value1, value2):

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    dictionary = manager.dict()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)

    #boolean_test is a function that gets one int and 2 strings as args
    for b in list_of_values:
        dictionary[b] = pool.apply_async(boolean_test,(b, value1, value2))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

So I want the processes to handle the whole list_of_values and saving each output in a dictionary with the key belonging to the output.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you probably expect something else than you get - you don't describe any error, just that something is wrong.

[As per documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult), apply_async returns `AsyncResult` object. You can extract your results with `.get` method (again, as per documentation).

To do so for the whole dictionary at once after `join` (all threads will exit by then), use list/dict comprehension:

```
{key: value.get() for (key, value) in dictionary.items()}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response

Comment: No problem. That's how I'm learning Python - browsing new questions and checking what I know or looking up new info while reading or trying to come up with an answer. ;)